# Can´t access keycloak due to wrong client password

Tags: java, keycloak, bad-request

I need a Java Keycloak(2.3) connection to return tokens, however I've ran into problems much earlier. When POST-requesting my Keycloak instance in Postman I get following errors in the particular console.

[This](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_development/topics/admin-rest-api.html) is the example from Keycloak my code is based on.

Keycloak:

```
17:54:47,586 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-25) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=admin-cli, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=password
```

Wildfly:

```
17:55:14,310 ERROR [stderr] (default task-48) javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

Java:

```
Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(
           KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_RESOURCE_URI,
           REALM,
           KEYCLOAK_USERNAME,
           KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD,
            KEYCLOAK_CLIENT);
    RealmRepresentation realm = keycloak.realm(REALM).toRepresentation();
```

Comment: From keycloak logs, your "admin" password is wrong

Comment: @ravthiru I can login on the webinterface with the same credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by changing my java code to the following

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
.serverUrl(KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_RESOURCE_URI)
.realm(REALM)
.username(KEYCLOAK_USERNAME)
.password(KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD)
.clientId(KEYCLOAK_CLIENT)
.clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Keycloak keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder().serverUrl(KEYCLOAK_TOKEN_RESOURCE_URI).realm(REALM)
            .username(KEYCLOAK_USERNAME).password(KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD).clientId(KEYCLOAK_CLIENT)
            .clientSecret("input-here-your-client-secret").build();
```

Maybe this should work, because Keycloak 2.3.Final has a Bug on the Keycloak.getInstance(...) method.